# How to get direction of travel using the only the GPS?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How can I get the direction of travel (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW) on an iPhone using only information from the GPS (longitude and latitude)?

I do not want to use the compass because it isn't always accurate.

Comment: Did you know that GPS isn't always accurate either?

Comment: You'd be surprised how accurate the GPS is. It's much more accurate than the Magnetometer, especially on the iPhone 4 and iPad. The compass has to deal with so much interference from the electronics around it.

Comment: Here's a question and answer about adding a category to CLLocation that easily calculates the bearing based only on a lat/lon pair: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925942/cllocation-category-for-calculating-bearing-w-haversine-function

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the current coordinates at two separate instants and subtract them. Here's some pseudocode (sorry, I don't speak Objective-C):

```
start <- get current position
wait some time
end <- get current position
direction = end - start
```

This will give you a vector that points in the current direction. To get it as an angle you can use the [vector dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

```
product <- start.lat * end.lat + start.lng * end.lng
start_length <- sqrt(start.lat^2 + start.lng^2)
end_length <- sqrt(end.lat^2 + end.lng^2)
angle <- arccos(product/(start_length * end_length))
```

Given the angle, you can easily get the cardinal direction. Just see which one is nearest.