# Moving a CLLocation by x meters

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location, latitude-longitude

I have a CLLocation defined, and I'd like to move that point x meters to the east and y meters to the south. How may I achieve that?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't always move north/south from all points on the globe -- for instance, if you're at the North Pole, you can only go south. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @duskwuff : To make it simple, I want my userPos to make 100 step to the right, and 100 step back :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a C function that is close to what you are asking but it takes a bearing and distance.  It's in my UtilitiesGeo class on [github](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/Utils/UtilitiesGeo.h).  You would pass the latitude and longitude from your CLLocation to it and then create a new CLLocation from the resulting lat2 and lon2 that it returns:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Given a starting lat/lon point on earth, distance (in meters)
* and bearing, calculates destination coordinates lat2/lon2.
*
* all params in degrees
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void destCoordsInDegrees(double lat1, double lon1,
                         double distanceMeters, double bearing,
                         double* lat2, double* lon2);
```

If you can't use that, take a look at the algorithms that it was derived from [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/calculation.html) and [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and perhaps you can modify it or those sites might have something closer to your needs.

Comment: that looks very very close (near perfect in fact) of what I'm searching for. Bearing param will help :-)  I'll try this tonight.

Comment: Does this function use distanceMeters as meters on the surface of the sphere, or through the sphere ?

Comment: Why do you normalize180 the longitude and not the latitude ?

Comment: normalize180 make the longitude so that it's always in the range of -180 to +180.

Comment: I have almost the same implementation (my implementation is equal with all of the answers ) but I have a problem for reverse the location again!
as far as I know, we should add -(distance) but it has an error ( in Decimal numbers and point to a little bit far place )  and I can't extract the original location again!
Any idea?

Answer (score 43):

A conversion to Swift, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490313/calculate-lat-long-coords-a-specific-distance-away-from-another-pair-of-lat-long):

> ```
> func locationWithBearing(bearingRadians:Double, distanceMeters:Double, origin:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
>     let distRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6) // earth radius in meters
>
>     let lat1 = origin.latitude * M_PI / 180
>     let lon1 = origin.longitude * M_PI / 180
>
>     let lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distRadians) * cos(bearingRadians))
>     let lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(bearingRadians) * sin(distRadians) * cos(lat1), cos(distRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2))
>
>     return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat2 * 180 / M_PI, longitude: lon2 * 180 / M_PI)
> }
> ```
>
> Morgan Chen wrote this:
>
> > All of the math in this method is done in radians. At the start of the
> > method, lon1 and lat1 are converted to radians for this purpose as
> > well. Bearing is in radians too. Keep in mind this method takes into
> > account the curvature of the Earth, which you don't really need to do
> > for small distances.

My comments (Mar. 25, 2021):

The calculation used in this method is called solving the "direct geodesic problem", and this is discussed in C.F.F. Karney's article "[Algorithms for geodesics](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z)", 2012. The code given above uses a technique that is less accurate than the algorithms presented in Karney's article.

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for the swift solution, but I need to correct one thing. Bearing should be in radian not double. I will post it as an answer since i can not paste the code here.

Comment: If it's unclear to anyone, bearing refers to the direction that you want to advance, in degrees, so for north: bearing = 0, for east: bearing = 90, for southwest: bearing = 225, etc...

Comment: One note on this is that it doesn't wrap (i.e. 181 lat doesn't wrap to -181).

Comment: @ShakedSayag note that bearing in the current iteration of the answer is in radians, so it would be so for north: bearing = 0, for east: bearing = 0.5 pi, for south: bearing = pi; etc..

Comment: Really good accuracy for the speed.  Nice solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Improved swift solution to Peters answer. Only correction is the bearing should be radian while calculation has been made.

```
 func locationWithBearing(bearing:Double, distanceMeters:Double, origin:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let distRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6)

    var rbearing = bearing * M_PI / 180.0

    let lat1 = origin.latitude * M_PI / 180
    let lon1 = origin.longitude * M_PI / 180

    let lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distRadians) * cos(rbearing))
    let lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(rbearing) * sin(distRadians) * cos(lat1), cos(distRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2))

    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat2 * 180 / M_PI, longitude: lon2 * 180 / M_PI)
}
```

Comment: I've applied your solution. Mostly it works fine but there is some deflection happening as well. Why is that. Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382149/moving-gmsmarker-by-x-meters-deflects

Comment: I have almost the same implementation (my implementation is equal with all of the answers ) but I have a problem for reverse the location again!
as far as I know, we should add -(distance) but it has an error ( in Decimal numbers and point to a little bit far place )  and I can't extract the original location again!
Any idea?

Answer (score 16):

Great post, here's the Obj-C wrapper for those who love copy/paste:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) locationWithBearing:(float)bearing distance:(float)distanceMeters fromLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)origin {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D target;
    const double distRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6); // earth radius in meters

    float lat1 = origin.latitude * M_PI / 180;
    float lon1 = origin.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float lat2 = asin( sin(lat1) * cos(distRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distRadians) * cos(bearing));
    float lon2 = lon1 + atan2( sin(bearing) * sin(distRadians) * cos(lat1),
                     cos(distRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) );

    target.latitude = lat2 * 180 / M_PI;
    target.longitude = lon2 * 180 / M_PI; // no need to normalize a heading in degrees to be within -179.999999° to 180.00000°

    return target;
}
```

Comment: Does not work correctly. Gives different location for the different distance with the same bearing.

Comment: In a situation where a vehicle is moving and you want to know the location and distance at the precise moment, another useful addition/improvement would be a computation of distance since the last location based on an estimate of the speed of the moving vehicle. I think you would do this by computing time from the GPS signal, the timestamp variable, lagged behind the device clock time. Apple devices sample GPS location at 1 hz, but third-party GPS receivers that have APIs that interact with CLLocation sample at 4 to 10 hz (the Dual 150 and 160 models, for example).

Answer (score 6):

Strange that nobody thought of using MKCoordinateRegion from MapKit to calculate that automatically.

```
import MapKit

extension CLLocation {
    func movedBy(latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance, longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance) -> CLLocation {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: abs(latitudinalMeters), longitudinalMeters: abs(longitudinalMeters))

        let latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta
        let longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta

        let latitudialSign = CLLocationDistance(latitudinalMeters.sign == .minus ? -1 : 1)
        let longitudialSign = CLLocationDistance(longitudinalMeters.sign == .minus ? -1 : 1)

        let newLatitude = coordinate.latitude + latitudialSign * latitudeDelta
        let newLongitude = coordinate.longitude + longitudialSign * longitudeDelta

        let newCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLatitude, longitude: newLongitude)

        let newLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: newCoordinate, altitude: altitude, horizontalAccuracy: horizontalAccuracy, verticalAccuracy: verticalAccuracy, course: course, speed: speed, timestamp: Date())

        return newLocation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Slight adjustment to @CocoaChris answer: now a category on CLLocation, and using the built-in units.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface CLLocation (Movement)

- (CLLocation *)locationByMovingDistance:(double)distanceMeters withBearing:(CLLocationDirection)bearingDegrees;

@end


@implementation CLLocation (Movement)

- (CLLocation *)locationByMovingDistance:(double)distanceMeters withBearing:(CLLocationDirection)bearingDegrees
{
    const double distanceRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6); // earth radius in meters
    const double bearingRadians = bearingDegrees * M_PI / 180;

    float lat1 = self.coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180;
    float lon1 = self.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180;

    float lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distanceRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distanceRadians) * cos(bearingRadians));
    float lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(bearingRadians) * sin(distanceRadians) * cos(lat1),
                              cos(distanceRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) );

    return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 * 180 / M_PI
                                      longitude:lon2 * 180 / M_PI];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have almost the same implementation (my implementation is equal with all of the answers ) but I have a problem for reverse the location again!
as far as I know, we should add -(distance) but it has an error ( in Decimal numbers and point to a little bit far place )  and I can't extract the original location again!
Any idea?

Comment: Hi @Mohamad, it could be a numerical precision error, have you tried using doubles instead of floats?

Comment: Hi @joerick
I'm using double and it's happening even in the reference website 
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
"Destination point given distance and bearing from start point"
I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution is to use MKMapPoints.

Convert your original coordinates, and any offset distances you need to MKMapPoints using this:

```
let coordinatesInMapPoints = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D)
let distancesInMapPoints = yourDistanceInMeters * MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(CLLocationDegrees) // Do this for both x and y directions if needed.
```

Then make a new MKMapPoint by simply adding your offset distances to your original coordinates:

```
let newCoordinatesInMapPoints = MKMapPointMake(coordinatesInMapPoints.x + distancesInMapPoints, coordinatesInMapPoints.y)
```

Finally, convert the new coordinates from a MKMapPoint back to CLLocationCoordinate2D:

```
let newCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(newCoordinatesInMapPoints)
```

No complex conversion calculations needed.

Comment: How to do it for y direction ?

Comment: If different offset distance, then repeat line 2 with a different "yourDistanceInMeters" and add that to "coordinatesInMapPoints.y". If same offset distance, then only need to add "distancesInMapPoints" to "coordinatesInMapPoints.y"

Answer (score 3):

Swift implementation using `Measurement` struct to do the conversions between degrees and radians.

```
class GPSLocation {

public class func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double {
        return Measurement(value: degrees, unit: UnitAngle.degrees).converted(to: .radians).value
    }

    public class func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double {
        return Measurement(value: radians, unit: UnitAngle.radians).converted(to: .degrees).value
    }

    public class func location(location: CLLocation, byMovingDistance distance: Double, withBearing bearingDegrees:CLLocationDirection) -> CLLocation {
        let distanceRadians: Double = distance / 6372797.6
        let bearingRadians: Double = GPSLocation.degreesToRadians(degrees: bearingDegrees)

        let lat1 = GPSLocation.degreesToRadians(degrees: location.coordinate.latitude)
        let lon1 = GPSLocation.degreesToRadians(degrees: location.coordinate.longitude)

        let lat2 = GPSLocation.radiansToDegrees(radians:asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distanceRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distanceRadians) * cos(bearingRadians)))
        let lon2 = GPSLocation.radiansToDegrees(radians:lon1 + atan2(sin(bearingRadians) * sin(distanceRadians * cos(lat1)), cos(distanceRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2)))

        return CLLocation(latitude: lat2, longitude: lon2)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 as a CGPoint extension

Derived from Peter O.'s solution

FloatingPoint extension: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2500428

```
extension FloatingPoint
{
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

extension CGPoint
{
    // NOTE: bearing is in radians
    func locationWithBearing(bearing: Double, distanceMeters: Double) -> CGPoint
    {
        let distRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6) // earth radius in meters

        let origLat = Double(self.y.degreesToRadians)
        let origLon = Double(self.x.degreesToRadians)

        let newLat = asin(sin(origLat) * cos(distRadians) + cos(origLat) * sin(distRadians) * cos(bearing))
        let newLon = origLon + atan2(sin(bearing) * sin(distRadians) * cos(origLat), cos(distRadians) - sin(origLat) * sin(newLat))

        return CGPoint(x: newLon.radiansToDegrees, y: newLat.radiansToDegrees)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let loc = CGPoint(x: lon, y: lat)
let newLoc = loc.locationWithBearing(bearing: 90.degreesToRadians, distanceMeters: 500.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    /// Get coordinate moved from current to `distanceMeters` meters with azimuth `azimuth` [0, Double.pi)
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - distanceMeters: the distance in meters
    ///   - azimuth: the azimuth (bearing)
    /// - Returns: new coordinate
    func shift(byDistance distanceMeters: Double, azimuth: Double) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let bearing = azimuth
        let origin = self
        let distRadians = distanceMeters / (6372797.6) // earth radius in meters

        let lat1 = origin.latitude * Double.pi / 180
        let lon1 = origin.longitude * Double.pi / 180

        let lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distRadians) + cos(lat1) * sin(distRadians) * cos(bearing))
        let lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(bearing) * sin(distRadians) * cos(lat1), cos(distRadians) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2))
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat2 * 180 / Double.pi, longitude: lon2 * 180 / Double.pi)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    let point: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    let north100 = point.shift(byDistance: 100, azimuth: 0) // 100m to North
    let south100 = point.shift(byDistance: 100, azimuth: Double.pi) // 100m to South
```

Comment: This is answer is very clear. Can you please share the azimuth values for "100m to East" and "100m to West"?

Comment: @thus West = pi/2, East = -pi/2

Comment: Does it work correctly for any angle[bearing]?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an updated answer to a measurement question, which includes an answer to this plotting one. Here: [CLLocation Category for Calculating Bearing w/ Haversine function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925942/cllocation-category-for-calculating-bearing-w-haversine-function/61391194#61391194)