# iOS MapKit - Getting random coordinates X miles from location

Tags: ios, random, mapkit, coordinates

I am interested in plotting random points within X miles of a user's location.
Is there a function/algorithm for finding a coordinate X miles (or meters) away from a given coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

1. You get coordinate of any map point with respect to the current location or any location of your choosing. [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241963/1336105 ]
2. Plot it on the map.