# Get direction of User by CLLocation

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location, angle

Hi, i am working on GPS ios app.

I want to display user's location on Circle as shown in image.

The user is in center.

I want to display his friend's location on proper direction.

I had already got langitude and latitude of both user .

But how can i get other user's direction?

If can i use Bearing angle?

[image]

I get the Distance between two uses by this code

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Latitude longitude:Longitude];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:app.lat longitude:app.lag];
CLLocationDistance distance = [locB distanceFromLocation:locA];
```

Thanks for Help!!

Comment: @RDC I already has distance between two location. I want Direction between this location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925942/cllocation-category-for-calculating-bearing-w-haversine-function) describing how to compute bearing using the haversine function

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using two ways :
1.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { c_lat, c_long };
CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { [[dic valueForKey:@"business_lat"]doubleValue], [[dic valueForKey:@"business_long"]doubleValue] };

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&",start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

2.

Using Google [API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling)

In API you just need to pass origin name and destination name

Hope this helped....

Comment: BY THIS I CAN ONLY DISPLAY THAT POINT IN GOOGLE POINT. I WANT TO DISPLAY IT IN MY UI AS SHOWN IN IMAGE.

Comment: @PriyankGandhi : Just parse google api responce and set data according your choise. Do not forget to pass your origin and destination.

Comment: @PriyankGandhi : Please check both answer.

Comment: I dont have source and Destination. I have two set of Longitude and latitude of Person which is constantly updated

Comment: @PriyankGandhi : Use first answer

Comment: @PriyankGandhi : If you want to use second answer then you need to get address from latlong using another google api.

Comment: But if i use first i can only display this in google Map right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28027/discussion-between-chirag-pipaliya-and-priyank-gandhi)