# Bearing of Current location in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, bearing

I have just completed an Android app, where I used bearing value of current location. Now I am trying to do same app for iOS. But did not find a way to get bearing of current location in iOS sdk?

I am not looking how to calculate bearing between two CLLocationCoordinate2Ds ([Calculating bearing between two CLLocationCoordinate2Ds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809337/calculating-bearing-between-two-cllocationcoordinate2ds?rq=1)).

*** I need bearing of current location.

Any help will be great for me.

Comment: dont see what you mean.. how can one location have a bearing? you need a TARGET to have a bearing to

Comment: post your code that you tried

Comment: In Android I used: currentBearing = currentLocation.getBearing();

Comment: @arefin can u please check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588865/ios-google-maps-keep-current-location-courseangle-always-north-like-google-nav

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CLLocation` has a `course` property (type `CLLocationDirection`) which is the bearing. From the docs:

> Course values are measured in degrees starting at due north and continuing clockwise around the compass. Thus, north is 0 degrees, east is 90 degrees, south is 180 degrees, and so on. Course values may not be available on all devices. A negative value indicates that the direction is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, @nevan king. I think I got my answer that I was looking for.

Comment: can to tell me how to use this course property @arefin

Comment: @nevan king. I am working with marker rotation in google maps, How can i set rotation for that, can u please guide me.

Comment: @ nevan king  Im getting course property. Im applying directly gmsmap view bearing. Is it correct or shall i need to apply for marker.rotation also ..
Can u please check my problem

Comment: I tried to use the same value, but I am always getting -1, am I doing something wrong? @arefin

Comment: @ParasGorasiya it's been a while since your comment, but I'm experiencing the same outcome (`-1`). Did you manage to get to the bottom of that mystery?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old but I will leave my answer that may help other people who pass by here.

```
class MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {

        self.bearing = position.bearing
    }
}
```

Using this delegate you can obtain the bearing related with camera rotation from the google maps SDK.