# How to find direction between two location in iPhone application?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to find direction between two location using iOS framework but I am not able to find proper solution .

Comment: Here is the tutorial. http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different methods for finding the direction between two location.

(1) Using Google Maps

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", currentLatitude, currentLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

(2) Using Apple Maps:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", currentLatitude, currentLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

Please let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 2):

your question is not very clear, but i think you mean the bearing between two locations.
see this question:
[Calculating bearing between two CLLocationCoordinate2Ds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809337/calculating-bearing-between-two-cllocationcoordinate2ds)

Answer (score 0):

If your points are close together just use trigonometry. That will be close enough. If they are farther away then you want a great circle course, use the Haversine formula.