# How to get directions from user location to another specific location?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have 2 locations in the map. First one is users current location with blue dot placemark and the second one is specified restaurant location near of the users current location with red dot placemark. I want to get directions from user's current location to restaurant location. I am getting directions when I define latitude and longitude values like `latitude: 38.00001 and longitude: 27.08980`.

Also I am getting each restaurants location from api to red dot placemark but do not get directions from user current location to restaurant location.

I am getting restaurant location with these codes:

```
var viewModel: DetailsViewModel? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
    willSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    if let viewModel = viewModel {
      detailsFoodView?.priceLabel?.text = viewModel.price
      detailsFoodView?.hoursLabel?.text = viewModel.isOpen
      detailsFoodView?.locationLabel?.text = viewModel.phoneNumber
      detailsFoodView?.ratingsLabel?.text = viewModel.rating
      detailsFoodView?.collectionView?.reloadData()
      centerMap(for: viewModel.coordinate)
      print("detail restaurant destination : \(viewModel.coordinate)")
      title = viewModel.name
      print("title: \(title)")
    }
}

func centerMap(for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    detailsFoodView?.mapView?.addAnnotation(annotation)
    detailsFoodView?.mapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}
```

**And in `viewDidLoad()` getting directions like:**

```
let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
```

**Problem is here**

I do not get each restaurant's latitude and longitude values to `destCoordinates`. Normally, I get with `viewModel.coordinate`.

**But if I use**

```
let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: viewModel?.coordinate.latitude, longitude: viewModel?.coordinate.longitude)
```

**Instead of:**

```
let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.420183, longitude: 27.205559)
```

I am getting latitude and longitude values nil or zero.

```
let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
let destPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)
    
let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMark)
    
let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
directionRequest.source = sourceItem
directionRequest.destination = destItem
directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
    
let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
directions.calculate(completionHandler: {response, error in
guard let response = response else {
 if error != nil {
 print("Something went wrong!")
  }
 return
    }
 let route = response.routes[0]
 self.detailsFoodView?.mapView?.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
        
 let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
      self.detailsFoodView?.mapView?.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
```

Expected result is current user place as blue dot placemark to red dot placemark with red line as you can see in the screen shot.

**Image:**
[image: Screenshot of map]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find direction between two location in iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809300/how-to-find-direction-between-two-location-in-iphone-application)

Comment: It sounds like you might want to take a look at `heading` for the user location. This does not work with the simulator as far as I can remember: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkuserlocation/1452721-heading

Comment: I try with physical device but nothing change @zero3nna. Problem is I do not get destination object to `destCoordinates`.

Comment: What is the difference between your two `let destCoordinates = ...` above?
And how are you setting the `viewModel.coordinate` value? @EmreDeğirmenci

Comment: @zero3nna I am so sorry! I copied same code twice! I edited!

Comment: well you can't set it this way: `let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: viewModel?...` because CLLocationCoord2D doesnt take optional lat or long values. But I would guess that your `viewModel` is `nil` at this point. Can you show us the full context of your code?

Comment: here is my full project on github:
https://github.com/emrdgrmnci/Locally/blob/master/Locally/Screen/Details/DetailsFoodViewController.swift