# Show the correct image associated with the directives of the direction instructions

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I have use the code below in order to get directions from my position and to show it in a list view.

```
-(void)getDirectionFromMyPosition:(id)sender{

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (!(networkStatus == NotReachable)) {
        MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
        [request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
        // Make the destination
        CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.lat,self.lon);
        MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoords addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];
        [request setDestination:destination];
        [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny]; // This can be limited to automobile and walking directions.
        [request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES]; // Gives you several route options.
        MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];


        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

            [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self animated:YES];
                });


                if (!error) {

                    NSArray *routes=[response routes];
                    if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calculatedRoute::)]) {
                        [delegate calculatedRoute:routes :(UIButton*)sender];
                    }

                    for (MKRoute *route in routes) {
                        [self.mapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the

                        [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[[route polyline] boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0) animated:YES];
                    }
                }else{
                    [self handleMapDirectionError];
                }
            }];
        });

    }else{
        [self handleNoInternet];
    }
}
```

But I don't know, how I can set the correct image that will be associate with the route directives.

I'd want obtain the result show in the below image:

[image]

Until now my brutal solution is that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"directionsDetailTableCell";

DirectionsDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[DirectionsDetailTableViewCell  alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


/*********************/
/*Le API ad oggi non tornano nulla che possa far capire quale immagine usare*/
/*********************/
NSString *str=[[self.steps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] instructions];
if(![str isEqualToString:@""]){

    UIImage *img=nil;
    if(([str rangeOfString:@"destinazione"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"destination"].length!=0)){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"destination.png"];
    }else if([str rangeOfString:@"Continua"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"Proceed"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"Continue"].length){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"continues.png"];
    }else if([str rangeOfString:@"sinistra"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"left"].length!=0){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"];
    }else if ([str rangeOfString:@"destra"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"right"].length!=0){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"];
    }else if(([str rangeOfString:@"rotonda"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"round"].length!=0)){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"round.png"];
    }else if(([str rangeOfString:@"uscita"].length!=0||[str rangeOfString:@"exit"].length!=0)){
        img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"exit.png"];
    }

    if(img!=nil){
        cell.img.image=img;
    }

    cell.lbltitle.text=[[self.steps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] instructions];
    cell.lbldescription.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f Km",[[self.steps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] distance]/1000];
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Try the following: Calculate the difference in bearing (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809337/calculating-bearing-between-two-cllocationcoordinate2ds) between the polylines of neighboring steps.  If the difference is say between -30 and +30 then say "proceed", if difference is +30 to +180 say "right", else say "left".

Comment: Good Idea! But the problem is only partially solved. In this mode I can't recognize roundabout and distinguish between a curve and a  "Take exit" in a motorway.

Comment: Yes, only partial.  I don't see anything in MKRouteStep that would help interpret the instructions automatically besides your brute force approach.